# "Replicate" sql structure between testing and staging on same database instance

Tags: sql-server

On my local development server I have a database set up which gets hooked into Entity-Framework and is then used for unit testing. Let's call it `COMPANY\Database`

On the same server (and same database instance) I then have another database - `COMPANY\DatabaseStaging` which has the exact same structure but persistent test data used for constructing a front end site around.

So, to hopefully clarify, the structure/flow is something like:

Create or modify a table:

> COMPANY\Database.Product

Update entity framework, write some business logic, unit tests, etc against the table.

Manually mirror/replicate the changes:

> COMPANY\DatabaseStaging.Product

Put in some slightly more persistent test data and do front end/ASP.NET stuff.

Now, this doesn't seem very elegant to be manually updating the `COMPANY\DatabaseStaging` database to make it reflect changes in `COMPANY\Database`. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: This seems to be a question about automating deployment of SQL Server schema and code changes. There are many different ways to achieve that: use [SSDT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx), use a [commercial product](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/), write your [own deployment tools and scripts](http://www.sommarskog.se/AbaPerls/index.html) etc. If you can make your question more precise, you may get a better response.

Answer (score 1):

There are many free tools - native and opensource available for comparing schema and data between 2 databases (on same or different servers):

1. [Open DBDiff](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=opendbiff) ==> This is on Codeplex and works great.
2. [SQL Admin Studio](https://web.archive.org/web/20170606225728/https://www.simego.com/products/sql-admin-studio) ==> This is now a free tool.
3. **Hidden Gem** from SQL 2005 and up :  [tablediff.exe](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2010/10/10/tablediff-exe-compare-and-synchronize-your-sql-server-tables/) (you can find this in the COM directory of your SQL Server install folder) Compare schemas: Regular or Strict
4. Powershell - You have to write your own code or build up on [existing ones](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307083620/http://poshcode.org:80/865)
5. If you are using SQL Server 2012, [SSDT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/12/13/available-today-ssdt-december-2012.aspx) is also an option.
6. I have not tried this one, but just to put it in place
   [SqlDiffFramework](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sqldiffframework)

From my experience, its worth to invest in Redgate's Schema and data compare tools as they have commandline options and they integrate well with Powershell as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of great tools to do this. A great tool that gives a decent value for its price is [xSQL Comparison Bundle](http://www.xsql.com/download/sql_server_comparison_bundle/?utm_source=pragmatic&utm_medium=articles&utm_campaign=xsql)  which is developed by the company i work at. It contains [xSQL Schema Compare](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_schema_compare/?utm_source=pragmatic&utm_medium=articles&utm_campaign=xsql) which can be used to compare the schema's of two databases and then generate the scripts to synchronize the schemas. It also contains [xSQL Data Compare](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_data_compare/?utm_source=pragmatic&utm_medium=articles&utm_campaign=xsql) which is used to compare the data in two databases.

Disclaimer: I'm affiliated to xSQL